# MMap and SharedArrays

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed

I am confronting a very weird problem when parallelizing some function. I understand that I am supposed to post a MWE but I could not recreate the issue in a simple problem.

```
@everywhere function simulSample(Profits,ν,J,TerminalT,RelevantT,N,S,params,thresh;RelevantPer=RelevantPeriod)
    Dₑ = rand([0],J,1) # Final Condition
    Dᵢ = rand([0],J,1) # Initial Condition
    tempData=SharedArray{Int8}(J,RelevantT,S*N)
    @inbounds @sync @distributed for n=1:S*N
    #for n=1:N
        #println(n)
        tempData[:,:,n]=solver(Dᵢ,Dₑ,Profits[:,:,n],continent,cont_lang,language,J,TerminalT,RelevantT,RelevantPeriod,params,thresh,ν[:,:,n])
    end
    return tempData
end
```

This function is being called by another function in an iterative procedure. In the first iteration it works, but in the second iteration I get the following error

```
SystemError: mmap: The operation completed successfully. 
#windowserror#45(::Nothing, ::typeof(Base.windowserror), ::Symbol, ::Bool) at error.jl:148
windowserror at error.jl:148 [inlined]
#mmap#1(::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(Mmap.mmap), ::Mmap.Anonymous, ::Type{Array{Int8,3}}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::Int64) at Mmap.jl:221
mmap(::Mmap.Anonymous, ::Type{Array{Int8,3}}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::Int64) at Mmap.jl:186
_shm_mmap_array(::Type, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::String, ::UInt16) at SharedArrays.jl:670
shm_mmap_array(::Type, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::String, ::UInt16) at SharedArrays.jl:649
#call#3(::Bool, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Type{SharedArray{Int8,3}}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}) at SharedArrays.jl:118
Type at SharedArrays.jl:105 [inlined]
#call#10 at SharedArrays.jl:161 [inlined]
Type at SharedArrays.jl:161 [inlined]
#call#15 at SharedArrays.jl:171 [inlined]
SharedArray{Int8,N} where N(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) at SharedArrays.jl:171
#simulatedMoments#67(::Float64, ::Int64, ::typeof(simulatedMoments), ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Array{Any,3}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64) at 13-Estimation_Stable.jl:1255
simulatedMoments at 13-Estimation_Stable.jl:1232 [inlined]
#gmm_fun#70(::Float64, ::Float64, ::Int64, ::typeof(gmm_fun), ::SharedArray{Int64,3}, ::Array{Any,3}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Float64,2}) at 13-Estimation_Stable.jl:1297
gmm_fun(::SharedArray{Int64,3}, ::Array{Any,3}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Float64,4}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Array,1}, ::Array{Float64,2}) at 13-Estimation_Stable.jl:1284
obj_function_final(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Any,1}) at 13-Estimation_Stable.jl:1370
top-level scope at util.jl:156
```

I am adding a MWE with the error that I get hoping it can make things more transparent:

```
using Distributed, SharedArrays

rmprocs()
addprocs()
big_array = rand(100,11,20000)

function donothing(a)
   shared_array = convert(SharedArray,a)
end

for i=1:1000
    donothing(big_array)
end
```

With the error:

```
SystemError: mmap: The operation completed successfully. 
#windowserror#45(::Nothing, ::typeof(Base.windowserror), ::Symbol, ::Bool) at error.jl:148
windowserror at error.jl:148 [inlined]
#mmap#1(::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(Mmap.mmap), ::Mmap.Anonymous, ::Type{Array{Float64,3}}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::Int64) at Mmap.jl:218
mmap(::Mmap.Anonymous, ::Type{Array{Float64,3}}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::Int64) at Mmap.jl:186
_shm_mmap_array(::Type, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::String, ::UInt16) at SharedArrays.jl:670
shm_mmap_array(::Type, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::String, ::UInt16) at SharedArrays.jl:649
#call#3(::Bool, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Type{SharedArray{Float64,3}}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}) at SharedArrays.jl:118
Type at SharedArrays.jl:105 [inlined]
Type at SharedArrays.jl:357 [inlined]
convert at SharedArrays.jl:369 [inlined]
donothing(::Array{Float64,3}) at mwproblem.jl:8
top-level scope at mwproblem.jl:12
```

Comment: Your function is distributing workload across all workers. It looks like a function that is normally callled from the master node. Why do you have `@everywhere` in front of it? Are you calling it from workers?

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your reply. I am a beginner in Julia and I am not very sure on which functions I should write @everywhere and where I should not. 

In any case it should be called from the Master Node. Do you think this might solve the issue?

Comment: `@everywhere` defines a function on master AND all worker nodes. For most scenario (and most likely yours) you want to use the master to orchestrate parallel jobs on workers. Try starting with the code in my answer.

Comment: I posted the full error I am getting if perhaps that is useful.

Comment: try a file-backed SharedArray (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SharedArrays/). If it solves the problem it means it is the memory issue.

Comment: No, it is not a memory issue.

Comment: I added a MWE in case it is useful.

Comment: your new MWE is consuming all available memory.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a MWE pattern for a scenario that should be similar to yours:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)
using SharedArrays


@everywhere function compute()
    rand() + myid()*100
end

function dothejob()
    s = SharedArray(zeros(10000000))
    @sync @distributed for i in 1:10000000
        s[i] = compute()
    end
    s
end

myres = dothejob();
```

Comment: and just to be sure, I should not `finalize(s)`  at any point?

Comment: I am afraid it is still not working. I did the correction you suggested, and indeed, my code looks like the MWE that you proposed. The second time I run my code I get the error `SystemError: mmap the operation completed successfully` @Przemyslaw. In the MWE, it does not happen.

Comment: Maybe you run out of memory? Try monitoring the usage. Consider reusing the `s` object. If it is not the memory perhaps you will need to bisect between non working and working code and find the line that causes trouble.

Comment: I believe that the problem must be of memory as you point out. However, it is weird that it runs the first time and not the second time. I “tried” to write the SharedArray in a local scope so that it is deleted every time the loop ends, but this does not seem to be happening.